# Useful UI themes that add value

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, color, themes, value

I am trying to research content about UI themes that add value. Normally this is associated with vanity customization, but I find certain themes quite useful.

- A high contrast theme is valuable for accessibility
- A monochrome theme helps developers/designers (DX) to spot design problems
- A dark theme... might be borderline real value and usefulness, but so many users demand this that even OS and browsers ship with this concept

Asking about theme styles that target specific problems is an open ended question. Although I would appreciate any extension to my list, I would like at a minimum to know if there is a established term in the UX field for this concern. Mostly I want a the magic words to start searching about it. So far I only get "TOP Best Themes" results, which is exactly what I do not care about.

Answer (score 1):

I think an obvious one that's missing would be another common accessibility theme but for colour blindness.

Another one that I know about is a theme that makes it easier to read in high intensity light (e.g. outdoors in the sun) for readability.

Actually, with the new [Material Design 3 theme builder feature](https://material.io/blog/material-theme-builder) for dynamic colours, there should be more flexibility and response to different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I find your question very interesting, and if you don't find the right answer, I would invite you to develop your own study and publish it.

---

I see the three examples you put refer to the use of color and based on this I found some more elements to add to the list. Although not all of them may be the wanted ones, from some you can get more information.

##### Descriptive alerts against color alerts

> Users who can not see the red characters can face some difficulties if they receive an error message similar to 'Please, correct the fields highlighted in red'. It is better not to refer to the particular color and give a more specific description such as, ‘Please, re-enter your email address and phone number’.

##### Complementary colors enhance readability

> Overlaying colors at opposite ends of the color wheel can make reading easier (avoiding maximum brightness / saturation)

##### Accent colors create focal points

> A sparsely used "accent" color immediately attracts visual attention. The more intense and saturated the color of an item, the more outstanding it is compared to its surroundings.

##### Blank spaces isolate relevant elements

> Blank prominent margins are useful to highlight relevant elements of information and conversion clicking points.

##### Color microinteractions aid UI intuition

> Interactions such as hover and active states should be included in the context of colors. For example, by changing the saturation level of the button basic color and making it more transparent or, on the contrary, bright, designers make the app more interactive and intuitive to use.

##### Branding colors create cohesion

> Using branding colors is how the design creates consistency of visual solutions that connect all communication channels of the company as well as enhances brand awareness.

##### Variety of color proportions generate interest

In some websites that describe the use of color in UI they talk about exact proportions such as 60, 30 and 10. Personally I'm an enemy of mathematical formulas applied to creativity, I only mention it as another existing element.

> Color schemes work best if the amounts of colors used for the design are not the same. A variety of proportions generates more interest.

<sub>*Sources [attentioninsight.com](https://attentioninsight.com/eye-catching-colors/), [uigstudio.com / role of colors in UX](https://uigstudio.com/insights/role-of-colors-in-ux-and-ui-design)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Regarding dark mode it reduces light emitted by device screens and can enhance visual ergonomics by reducing eye strain. However a bit depending on the light in the environment your in. That’s why in like MacOS you can set it to auto, so when it’s light outside the theme is light, and dark outside its dark mode. Here’s an article describing it in a bit more detail  https://www.techaheadcorp.com/blog/dark-mode

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65957)

Comment: Wasn’t that exactly what I did @Devin? Think you need to read the answers before reviewing